# DB2 and Reverting last update table

Tags: db2, sql-update, revert

I just accidentaly updated a whole table, I set a column value without a where, and now, 80 registries have that value :s, is there a way to revert that? I don't want to be murdered by my boss.

Comment: Depending on what those entries represent, the first thing you need to do is **tell your boss**; there could be legal/moral implications if you fail to do so.  Note that restoring from a backup can be expensive, so you may have to go through him anyways.  If it's not something important, and have other sources for the data, you may be able to restore it without bothering him immediately... just be prepared to report it.  This should be a learning experience for you - I know I was a lot more cautious after doing this.

Comment: Another piece of too-late advice: If you are going to update a production table, take a backup or export of the entire table first.

Answer (score 0):

You can "revert" the table if you are using archive logging. You restore a backup and perform roll forward to just before your update. It is not that easy, but you can "undo" that update.